# inner join in Sql Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this query with using subquery but not able to fetch my result .is any one here to help me in geting it correct.

```
SELECT u.uv_id ID
     , d.sd_code Code
     , u.uv_name Title
     , u.uv_nirf Nirf
     , (SELECT sd_code 
          FROM vm_university_type t
          JOIN vm_seo_detail d
            ON t.ut_id = d.sd_ty_id 
           AND d.sd_ty = 'vm_university_type') AS 'University Type' 
     , a.ab_name 'Approved By' 
     , u.uv_seats Seats
     , g.ug_name 'University Group'
  FROM vm_universities u
  JOIN vm_seo_detail d
    ON u.uv_id = d.sd_ty_id 
   AND d.sd_ty = 'vm_universities'
  JOIN vm_university_type t
    ON u.uv_ut_id = t.ut_id
  JOIN vm_approved_by a
    ON u.uv_ab_id = a.ab_id
  JOIN vm_caste c
    ON u.uv_c_id = c.caste_id
  JOIN vm_university_groups g
    ON u.uv_ug_ids = g.ug_id;
```

i got this error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: limit your subquery to return only one row.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: sir i debug my query again and finnaly get what i need thank you for help...@TabAlleman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(SELECT `sd_code` FROM vm_university_type INNER JOIN vm_seo_detail ON (vm_university_type.ut_id = vm_seo_detail.sd_ty_id AND vm_seo_detail.sd_ty = 'vm_university_type') WHERE vm_university_type.ut_id=vm_universities.uv_ut_id ) AS 'University Type' ,
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need subquery at all. The column `Code` in `SELECT` statement contains `University Type`

Try below query.

```
SELECT vm_universities.uv_id AS 'ID' , vm_seo_detail.sd_code AS 'Code', 
vm_universities.uv_name AS 'Title' , vm_universities.uv_nirf AS 'Nirf', 
vm_approved_by.ab_name AS 'Approved By' , vm_universities.uv_seats as 'Seats',
vm_university_groups.ug_name AS 'University Group'
FROM vm_universities INNER JOIN vm_seo_detail
ON (vm_universities.uv_id = vm_seo_detail.sd_ty_id
      AND vm_seo_detail.sd_ty = 'vm_universities')
INNER JOIN vm_university_type
ON (vm_universities.uv_ut_id = vm_university_type.ut_id) 
INNER JOIN vm_approved_by
ON (vm_universities.uv_ab_id = vm_approved_by.ab_id) 
INNER JOIN vm_caste
ON (vm_universities.uv_c_id = vm_caste.caste_id) 
INNER JOIN vm_university_groups
ON (vm_universities.uv_ug_ids = vm_university_groups.ug_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `sd_code` FROM vm_university_type INNER JOIN vm_seo_detail ON (vm_university_type.ut_id = vm_seo_detail.sd_ty_id AND vm_seo_detail.sd_ty = 'vm_university_type')
```

looks like you forgot WHERE section in subquery, that will bind it to main query. something like

```
WHERE vm_university_type.ut_id=vm_universities.uv_ut_id
```

ps. and why you need this subquery at all, if you already join with vm_university_type in main query?

Comment: how to add it ..?

Comment: well i have stored my "sd_code" in vm_seo_details table i want to fetch it from seo_details table..